# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() Return FileNotFound Exception On Windows CE

Tags: .net, vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have a Visual Basic .NET application running against the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 on a Symbol handheld scanner running Windows CE 6.5.  From the Windows Form VB app, I'm trying to launch an IE window with a given URL when the user clicks a button.

```
Private Sub btnViewUpdateSite_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnViewUpdateSite.Click

    Process.Start("iesample.exe", "http://getupdate.localdomain.com")

End Sub
```

When I click the button from the app on the device, I get a FileNotFoundException on the line of code the "starts" the process.

What I don't understand is - While the program has stopped on the error, I can click in the Watch window in Visual Studio, copy and paste the code, and have the browser fire up the page.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Consider also using the webbrowser control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows CE does not have any concept of a "working directory" therefore you must provide fully qualified paths for any file.  Try this:

```
Process.Start(@"\Windows\iesample.exe", "http://getupdate.localdomain.com")
```

Comment: I tried it - same thing ... I rebooted the development machine, tried it again, and it works!